# pygmt plotting points plots polygons instead

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to plot a point shapefile in pygmt but plt.show output polygons

```
    import pygmt
    import geopandas as gpd
    import rasterio as rio
    import rioxarray as rxr
    from pathlib import Path
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    
    data = gpd.read_file(p / "data.shp")
    data.to_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

# collect extent region
bound = data.total_bounds
region = [bound[0], bound[2], bound[1], bound[3]]
# plot
fig = pygmt.Figure()
fig.basemap(region=region, projection="M20c", frame=True)
fig.plot(x=data.geometry.x, y=data.geometry.y, label="data")
fig.legend(position="jTL+o0.2c", box='+gwhite+p1p')
fig.show()
```

data.geometry looks like this:

```
data.geometry
0      POINT (176.91217 -39.47647)
1      POINT (176.90588 -39.51614)
2      POINT (176.83520 -39.60745)
3      POINT (176.91565 -39.52388)
4      POINT (176.91464 -39.52216)
                  ...             
865    POINT (176.91442 -39.51362)
866    POINT (176.89232 -39.51546)
867    POINT (176.78864 -39.62271)
868    POINT (176.87372 -39.51477)
869    POINT (176.91440 -39.51386)
Name: geometry, Length: 870, dtype: geometry
```

and the results is shown below:

[image: results]

I don't understand why I am getting polygons / lines instead of points

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Use `scatter` to plot the data as points.

Answer (score 0):

The `style` parameter is missing in your `fig.plot()` line. If `style` is not used, a line connecting the data points will be drawn instead (see https://www.pygmt.org/latest/api/generated/pygmt.Figure.plot.html#pygmt.Figure.plot). To plot points instead, simply try e.g.:

```
fig = pygmt.Figure()
fig.basemap(region=region, projection="M20c", frame=True)
fig.plot(x=data.geometry.x, y=data.geometry.y, label="data", style = "c0.5c")
fig.legend(position="jTL+o0.2c", box='+gwhite+p1p')
fig.show()
```